# Workspace is twice the size of my monitor

Tags: screen, monitor

Recently, I have this annoying problem in Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome-fallback: My only workspace width has become twice the size of my monitor (a 19" Philips). Because of this, some applications, like gnome user interface, go to to the right part of the workstation and become reachable.
I have installed CompizeConfig Settings manager and set all Desktop sizes to '1'. but it did not sove the problem.

I really appreciate your hints to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

1. Open the System Setting
2. In the hardware, open the display
3. You will see 2 “inside moniter”, you should click one to close.

Then the workspace will show one monitor.